# Как правильно сгруппировать данные в БД sql Android studio?

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, android-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сгруппировать данные в БД, представим что есть приложение связанная с расходами, финансы. В нем имеется категории такие как затраты на продукты и на авто т.п. так вот, вопрос нужно ли создавать каждый раз новую таблицу называя ее именем категории или как то по другому это можно сделать? Заранее благодарю за помощь!!

Comment: *нужно ли создавать каждый раз новую таблицу* Нет. Категория затрат - всего лишь атрибут, он не делает затрату новой сущностью.

Comment: Могли бы вы написать или тыкнуть как грамотно это сделать?

Comment: То есть в БД я должен заранее создать таблицу с категориями и уже вносить туда данные а затем искать по group by category  и сортировать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, нужно добавить столбец "категории" в таблицу, и потом через запросы sql находить по категориям, запросов много. Скачал sqlmanager там как раз таки есть все команды.